# Chrome-extension script inserting crossorigin attribute in video (in google cloud storage) tag when react render component more than once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, html5-video, google-cloud-storage

I have a React Component with a tag  loading a video from Google Cloud Storage. If my component call render only once, ok, but if it call render multiple times, a google-chome script called page.js insert a attribute crossorigin in my tag and it gives me a crossorigin error:

> Failed to load https://storage.cloud.google.com/bobguarana/SampleVideo_1280x720_1mb.mp4: Redirect from 'https://storage.cloud.google.com/bobguarana/SampleVideo_1280x720_1mb.mp4' to 'https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=cds&passive=1209600&continue=https://storage.cloud.google.com/bobguarana/SampleVideo_1280x720_1mb.mp4&followup=https://storage.cloud.google.com/bobguarana/SampleVideo_1280x720_1mb.mp4' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.

I already enabled CORS in the google bucket.

I dont't know if it helps, but the piece of code of the chrome script doing it is the follow:

```
var crossorigin = target.getAttribute('crossorigin');
                    //console.log(target);
                    if (src) {
                        //console.log('src', src);
                        //only reload if domains are not the same (so crossorigin attribute can kick in)
                        //console.log(src, getHostName(src), document.location.hostname, (crossorigin ? crossorigin : 'anonymous'));
                        if (document.location.hostname != getHostName(src) && 'blob:' != src.substring(0, 5) && !crossorigin) {
                            target.setAttribute('crossorigin', (crossorigin ? crossorigin : 'anonymous'));
                            //target.setAttribute('preload', 'auto');
                            //force "reload" so addedd crossorigin attribute can kick in
                            if (target.src) {
                                target.src = ''+target.src;
                                //target.load();
                            } else {
                                if (target.currentSrc) {
                                    target.load();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        //setTimeout(function(){
                        //  console.dir(target);
                        //},2000)
                        //console.log(target.src)
                        //console.log(target.currentSrc)
                        //console.dir(target);

                        source = audioContext.createMediaElementSource(target);
                        //read the source channel count
                        filters[0]._defaultChannelCount = (source.channelCount) ? source.channelCount : 2;
                        source.connect(filters[0]);
                        var totalFilters = filters.length;
                        var node;
                        for (var i = 0; i < totalFilters; i++) {
                            node = filters[i + 1];
                            if (node) {
                                filters[i].connect(node);
                            }
                        }

                        filters[filters.length - 1].connect(audioContext.destination);
                        target.setAttribute("eq-attached", "true");
```

I wish I did not have to mess with the front end, because i have a lot of state variables and is a complex component doing a lot of things.

I already tried to subscribe shouldcomponentupdate to false in react, but it did not work too.

I also noticed that, the the request header of the first request is different from the second one.

Comment: OK, i solved id. It was a conflict with the EQ app chrome-extension